# Saída Incorreta ao Imprimir Elementos de um Array

Tags: java

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Turma turma = new Turma("Est. de dados","A1","20191");
        turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Anselmo",111));
        turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Pedro",222));
        turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Joao",333));
        turma.imprimir();
    }

}
public class Aluno {
    String nome;
    int matricula;
    public Aluno(String nome, int matricula) {
        this.nome=nome;
        this.matricula=matricula;
    }
}
public class Turma {
    String nome;
    String codigo;
    String periodo;
    List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    public Turma(String nome, String codigo, String periodo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.periodo = periodo; 
    }
    public void imprimir() {
        for (Aluno b: alunos) { 
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
public void inserirAluno(Aluno a) {
    alunos.add(a);
}
```

}

Saída

```
Teste.Aluno@1db9742
Teste.Aluno@106d69c
Teste.Aluno@52e922
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você tenta imprimir um objeto diretamente, ele imprime o endereço de memória onde o objeto está alocado... Ou seja não se pode printar diretamente o b, existem duas formas de fazer isso...

1º)
   Na classe alunos você sobrescreve o método `ToString()` retornando uma String concatenada com os dados que você quer... Exemplo:

```
public String toString(){
   return "Nome: " + this.nome + ", Matricula: " + this.matricula;
}
```

Isso dentro da classe Aluno

Já no print é so colocar: `b.toString()`

2º)
   Informar dentro do print mesmo `b.nome`, `b.matricula`

Eu acho melhor fazer a primeira forma, mas aí vai de cada um!

Comment: obrigado Amigo funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

'b' é um objeto("Aluno"), para você conseguir imprimir os valores de cada objeto você deve usar o método toString(). exemplo: b.toString()

O método toString() você pode sobrescrever, definindo uma estrutura diferente caso queira alterar a saída.